# For finitely generated $B$ all modules in exact sequence are finitely generated in PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, exact-sequence, noetherian

Let there be an exact sequence of $R$-modules:
$$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$$
where $R$ is a principal ideal domain and $B$ is finitely generated.

> Are $A$ and $C$ finitely generated?

I know they are, because $C$ is isomorphic with $B/A$ and $A$ is isomorphic with a submodule of $B$ and PIDs are noetherian. But I don't fully understand this reasoning, could someone explain it a bit more?

Comment: Do you know what is a noetherian ring module? Alternatively, do you know the Fundamental Structure theorem for finitely generated modules over PIDs (or for abelian groups, which is a special case)?

Comment: @Bernard there is no infinitely increasing chain of ideals in $R$

Comment: Yes, and also any ideal is finitely generated. And a finitely generated  module over a noetherian ring is a noetherian module, i.e. all its submodules are finitely generated/there is no infinite increasing chain of submodules.